# Magento - AJAX newsletter validate e-mails that already exist in the database

Tags: javascript, ajax, validation, magento

I'm using this `ajax validation` but it doesn't validate if the e-mail already exists in the database. It just goes through if you entered a valid e-mail address:

```
onSubmit="if(newsletterSubscriberFormDetail.validator.validate())
 {
   new Ajax.Updater({success:'newsletter-validate-detail'}, 'newsletter/subscriber/new', 
     { 
       asynchronous:true, evalScripts:false, onComplete:function(request, json) 
     {
       Element.hide('newsletter-validate-detail');Element.show('pop-confirm');
     },  
       onLoading:function(request, json){}, parameters:Form.serialize(this)
     }); 
 } return false;"
```

I have tried to modify the onsubmit function, but to no avail. I hope someone here can teach me how to make this validation work so that it will check if the entered e-mail already exists.

Answer (score 0):

This is standard Magento behavior.
It doesn't check if the email already exists and always says "Thank you for your subscription".

You can check in `Mage_Newsletter_SubscriberController`in `newAction` that it'll only check for existing email if you're logged in and try to enter someone else's email address :

```
if ($ownerId !== null && $ownerId != $customerSession->getId()) {
    Mage::throwException($this->__('This email address is already assigned to another user.'));
}
```

You'll probably need to rewrite this method to achieve that '**Email already exists**' error.